# Read web.config values from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to read an app key from the web.config file via java script.
The web.config key to be read

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="Key1" value="value1" />
<appSettings>
```

I include the following inside my java script function.

```
function Evaluate() {
    var key = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"].ToString() %>';
    alert(key);
}
```

However, I end up getting `<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"].ToString() %>` in the alert.

What am i missing?

Comment: Your JS code is not being processed by the ASP engine. Where are you putting it?

Comment: bfavaretto is right. You could define a javascript variable in your ASPX containing the value you need.

Comment: I am putting it inside an external javascript file . The link to this file is given inside the webform.aspx page as <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js' /> Should I only include it inside the aspx page itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `<%= =>` tag is only going to execute if it is within a `.aspx` file.  If you place it within a .js file, then it will just be like any other text.  In order for your code to work, the javascript you posted would have to be embedded within the .aspx file.

Comment: Ok, so Let's say I create a global variable inside my aspx page as <script type="text/javascript"> var key1 = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"].ToString() %>'</script>. Is there a way I can access key1 from my external javascript file?  I do not want to embed the entire function code in my aspx page.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to access it from the external javascript file.  Don't include `var` if you want the variable to be truly global.  `<script type="text/javascript"> key1 = <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"].ToString() %>'</script>`

Comment: on the web.Config:
</appSettings>
    <add key="varName" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
On the html page:

<script>
    var varName= '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["varName"]';
</script>

Answer (score 5):

After to put the values on the config file, on the page that you will use the value put the java script this way bellow: You will access the value in the java script as a global, not necessary to declare it.

on the web config:

```
 </appSettings>
    <add key="varName" value="1" />
  </appSettings>
```

on the html page:

```
<script>
    var varName= '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["varName"]';
</script>
```

Comment: How can I convert varName in a List<string> if I don't know how many key are present in appSettings ?

Comment: There is a typo in the first appSettings tag.  remove the slash.